# Mysql: Null fields in final field despite file contents containing data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data file that i am using to insert into DB. As you can see, the final field's value is 4 in both lines of file.

```
2018-08-03 07:04:20     2       NODE_HEALTH_CHECK       Report_administrator_03082018065538     1       2018-08-03 07:04:17     2018-08-03 07:04:20     00:00:00:2:7210COMPLETED       FAILED  0       PRE_INSTALL     4
2018-08-03 12:33:30     2       NODE_HEALTH_CHECK       Report_administrator_03082018110136     2       2018-08-03 12:17:57     2018-08-03 12:33:30     00:00:15:33:116100     COMPLETED       SUCCESS 2       PRE_INSTALL     4
```

which i am inserting into my table via command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$bcpFileNhcDetailsLogs' INTO TABLE details_logs
```

Content of table after has NULL for both.

```
time    siteid  jobType job_name        number_of_network_elements      start_time      end_time        duration        progress_percentage     status  result  health_status  healthy_nodes_count     category        netypeid1
2018-08-03 07:04:20     2       NODE_HEALTH_CHECK       Report_administrator_03082018065538     1       2018-08-03 07:04:17     2018-08-03 07:04:20     00:00:00:2:7210COMPLETED       FAILED  0       0       4       NULL
2018-08-03 12:33:30     2       NODE_HEALTH_CHECK       Report_administrator_03082018110136     2       2018-08-03 12:17:57     2018-08-03 12:33:30     00:00:15:33:116100     COMPLETED       SUCCESS 2       0       4       NULL
```

I don't get why. See the table description, specifically the final field netypeid.

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default Extra
time    datetime        NO      MUL     NULL
siteid  smallint(5) unsigned    NO              NULL
jobType varchar(32)     NO              NULL
job_name        varchar(100)    NO              NULL
number_of_network_elements      smallint(5) unsigned    NO              NULL
start_time      datetime        NO              NULL
end_time        datetime        NO              NULL
duration        varchar(100)    NO              NULL
progress_percentage     smallint(5) unsigned    NO              NULL
status  varchar(20)     NO              NULL
result  varchar(20)     NO              NULL
health_status   varchar(20)     YES             NULL
healthy_nodes_count     smallint(5) unsigned    YES             NULL
category        varchar(32)     YES             NULL
netypeid        smallint(5) unsigned    YES             NULL
```

Comment: It appears as if you have after 'COMPLETED', which seems to fit in the status field  5 more fields in your table whereas you have 4 values in the file.  That would leave the last field always as null (and also explains where the '4' in the before-last field comes from as well as the disappearance of PRE_INSTALL)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you don't have a matching set of columns in your input data as you do in your data table definition.

The way they line up in the first row:

```
time = 2018-08-03 07:04:20
siteid = 2
jobType = NODE_HEALTH_CHECK       
job_name = Report_administrator_03082018065538
number_of_network_elements = 1 
start_time = 2018-08-03 07:04:17 
end_time = 2018-08-03 07:04:20 
duration = 00:00:00:2:721 
progress_percentage = 0 
status = COMPLETED 
result = FAILED 
health_status = 0 
healthy_nodes_count = PRE_INSTALL    ### Missing value from imported data - displays as '0'
category = 4 
netypeid1 = NULL
```

From what it looks like, I would guess that your `health_status` column is missing in your data import, resulting in the imported data getting shifted to the left one column. That leaves NULL to be added to the `nettypeid` field, and the imported `healthy_nodes_count` being set to `0` since your imported field is expecting a `smallint` and receiving a varchar string instead.

If you delete the `healthy_nodes_count` column out of your database table, the import should work properly. Otherwise, you will need to make sure that field is added to the data before importing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, between your clues and my own lightbulb moment, i realised that the column health_status was redundant. Dropped it from table and we're good!

Much appreciated